# What are some more descriptive words for a person who is strong and independent

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for one word descriptive words for someone who is strong and independent because that is two words and I am looking for one but somehow want to incorporate both words into the same 1 word

Comment: @KannE 'strong', 'independent'

Comment: Maybe "femme fatale" in some contexts? (It is completely borrowed from french)

Comment: Noun, adjective? Do you have an example sentence? Something contemporary and colloquial, or a classical or literary reference? (There are actually a lot of negative terms and very few positive ones.)

Comment: Thanks for the edits but give an example sentence and we'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @KannE 'Fierce' is a good answer (there are other questions on ELU that go through the PTMFO varieties).